# Help with improveProb function in Hmisc in R

Tags: r

Please bear with me, I am very new to R.

My question is regarding the use of the `improveProb` function in the `Hmisc` package. I have two logistic models, the only difference being that the second model contains my novel marker of interest. I am trying to calculate NRI and IDI.

I have the PredRisks for both models - PredRisk1 and PredRisk2, and my outcome is disease 0/1. How do I define this in R in order to run

`improveProb(x1, x2, y)`?

---

The data are the same for both models. We are looking at ways to validate our findings. We have performed k-fold cross-validation (MSE=0.08) and bootstrapping with optimism (AUC original = 0.826 After correction =0.791) to check for overfitting. Is this appropriate? The LRT was significant for both logistic regression models, but I need to check this. Also, the AIC for model 2 is lower than model 1. Thanks again for your expert knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

That would be `improveProb(PredRisk1, PredRisk2, y)`.  Note that this is to be done strictly in a supplemental way and not as a replacement for the gold standard likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test for added information.  And if you use $P$-values from NRI, IDI they will be approximate if $y$ was from the same data used to fit the models.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have since discovered that my two models were for different numbers of individuals (due to missing data on the novel variable) and have since rectified them. The function is now working correctly.

Comment: But that doesn't address the issue of whether the data are external to those data used in model developments.